# How to estimate the offset between two servers A and B

Tags: time, distributed-system, clock-synchronization

How to estimate the offset between two servers A and B using their timestamps from messages sent between them and the time they were sent/recieved?

Comment: Imagine that. I typed "clock synchronization algorithm" into google and one of the first hits was a wikipedia page listing the various algorithms.

Comment: I figured out how to get the offset. How would I tell how accurate the offset estimate is?

Comment: Try following the links in the Wikipedia article to some of the algorithms. Time synchronization isn't a new problem. There are known solutions, and probably even example code out there.

Comment: Your only hard guarantees are that the message hit the server sometime after you sent it and after you received the response. One-way delays are possible.